# Joomla 3.2 get form component from module

Tags: php, joomla

I created a module that get a form of a component but it works only in the pages of the component.

My class module helper :

```
class ModReservationHelper
{
    public static function &getForm()
    {
       jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
       JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_booking/models');
       $Model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'ReservationForm', 'BookingModel' );

        return $Model->getForm();
    }
}
```

The form return only on the component page, i need the form in all page ....

Comment: it really depends on the model, not on the module helper.  If the model is using component-related paths i.e. JPATH_COMPONENT constant, it will never work outside of the component.  Check the error log and update your question with the actual problem or code from the model.

Answer (score 3):

You can use another method:

```
// create new JForm object
$myForm = new JForm('MyForm');

// Load any form .xml file you want (like registration.xml)
$myForm->loadFile(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml');
```

Now you can render this object like any other Joomla! form (foreach ($myForm->getFieldsets() as $fieldset), etc.).
Remember to add suitable **option** and **task** fields and **form.token** of course.